# Control the distance between table of contents elements

Tags: table-of-contents, lengths, titletoc

I want to understand what are the lengths `dimension #1` and `#2` in the following example.

Moreover, is the blue dimension in the picture equals the length of `\parskip`?

How can I control the dimensions `#1` and `#2` with titletoc? I created two new lengths in the MWE, how can I pass them as the correct arguments of `\titlecontents{section}[]{}{}{}{}[]` and `\titlecontents{chapter}[]{}{}{}{}[]`?

[image]

```latex
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{titletoc}
  \dottedcontents{section}[3.8em]{}{2.3em}{0pc}
  \dottedcontents{subsection}[6.1em]{}{3.2em}{0pc}

\newlength\dimone \setlength\dimone{8pt}  % << new length
\newlength\dimtwo \setlength\dimtwo{14pt} % << new length

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{one}
\subsection{a}
\subsection{b}
\subsection{c}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\section*{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Exercises}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Exercises}
\chapter{second chapter}
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section{one}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I stand corrected.  The 10pt is only added to the lof and lot files (`\addvspace {10\p@ }`)  You need to look at `\l@chapter`, `\l@section` etc. to get the vertical space (ignore that some of them are negative).  Keep in mind that the code being implemented could be modified from the default from book.cls.

Comment: `\l@chapter` from book.cls uses `\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@` while the rest use `\vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@` (from `\@dottedtocline`).  In other words, 0pt plus glue.,  Since each entry is a paragraph, `\parskip` is being added as well.

Comment: `\tableofcontents` uses `\chapter*` which adds `\vspace*{50\p@}` (50pt) above and `\vskip 40\p@` (40pt) below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Kormylo has addressed the first part of your question in his answer, so I will answer only the second part.

Firstly, we would like to remove the extra space added by `\parskip` (which usually should not be changed manually). It can be done with the `parskip` package, as it is meant just for that, but this package does not patch `chapters`, so we will to do that ourselves.

With the following code you will get the original vertical spacing before and after sectioning headings and toc entries:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage[skip=10pt,parfill]{parskip}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@makeschapterhead{\parindent\z@}{\parskip\z@\parindent\z@}{}{}
\patchcmd\@makechapterhead{\parindent\z@}{\parskip\z@\parindent\z@}{}{}
\patchcmd\@starttoc{\vskip-\lastskip\vskip\skip@}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titletoc}
\dottedcontents{section}[3.8em]{}{2.3em}{0pc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[6.1em]{}{3.2em}{0pc}

\newlength\dimone \setlength\dimone{8pt}  % << new length
\newlength\dimtwo \setlength\dimtwo{14pt} % << new length

\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{First chapter\the\parskip}
    \section{one}
    \subsection{a}
    \subsection{b}
    \subsection{c}
    \section{two}
    \section{three}
    \section*{Summary}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
    \section*{Exercises}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Exercises}
    \chapter{second chapter}
    \section*{Introduction}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
    \section{one}
    \section{two}
    \section{three}
\end{document}
```

Now that we have retrieved the original spacing, we can start modifying them to our desire.

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\usepackage[skip=10pt,parfill]{parskip}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@makeschapterhead{\parindent\z@}{\parskip\z@\parindent\z@}{}{}
\patchcmd\@makechapterhead{\parindent\z@}{\parskip\z@\parindent\z@}{}{}
\patchcmd\@starttoc{\vskip-\lastskip\vskip\skip@}{\vskip-\lastskip\vskip\dimexpr\dimone-\dimtwo\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titletoc}
\dottedcontents{chapter}[1.5em]{\addvspace\dimtwo}{1em}{0pc}
\dottedcontents{section}[3.8em]{}{2.3em}{0pc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[6.1em]{}{3.2em}{0pc}


\newlength\dimone \setlength\dimone{8pt}  % << new length
\newlength\dimtwo \setlength\dimtwo{14pt} % << new length

\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{First chapter\the\parskip}
    \section{one}
    \subsection{a}
    \subsection{b}
    \subsection{c}
    \section{two}
    \section{three}
    \section*{Summary}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
    \section*{Exercises}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Exercises}
    \chapter{second chapter}
    \section*{Introduction}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
    \section{one}
    \section{two}
    \section{three}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The goal here is not to change the spacing, but to verify it.  Note that 1em is fontsize dependent, hense `\chapskip`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newlength{\chapskip}
\setlength{\chapskip}{1em}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents\hfill\llap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\smash{\rule[-40pt]{1pt}{40pt}}}}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter\hfill\strut\llap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\smash{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr \baselineskip+\chapskip+\parskip}}}}
\section{one\hfill\llap{\rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.5pt}\smash{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr \baselineskip+\parskip}}}}
\subsection{a\hfill\llap{\rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.5pt}\smash{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr \baselineskip+\parskip}}}}
\subsection{b}
\subsection{c}
\section{two}
\section{three}
\section*{Summary}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\section*{Exercises}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Exercises\hfill\llap{\rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.5pt}}}
\chapter{second chapter\hfill\strut\llap{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\smash{\rule{1pt}{\dimexpr \baselineskip+\chapskip+\parskip}}}}
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\section{one}
\section{two}
\section{three}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: So there is a length which is equal to `1em` and is used as a vskip between chapter entries in the TOC. You defined it to be `chapskip`, but can you tell me what is its original name and where it is defined?

Comment: `\l@chapter` from `report.cls` contains `\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@`.  I only used `\chapskip` to make it a fixed size, as opposed to getting larger inside the chapter title.